# Mail.app plugin - a toolbar button

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, plugins, apple-mail

How could I add a button to the Apple Mail's toolbar?

As i understand, I need to "swizzle" some methods of the MessageViewer class (this is the first responder window of the Mail.app).
Thanks to several open source Mail plugins, I managed to implement a basic plugin that can display windows, sheets, react on events.. I also managed to get a class dump of the Mail.app that lists all of the classes/methods of the Mail.app.

I've seen several people claimed to have implemented this, also a free Mail Archive plugin adds a button to the toolbar..

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: HEllo, Have you find the way, How to add button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is.

[BetterDictionary](https://github.com/pooriaazimi/BetterDictionary) is a Dictionary.app plugin I wrote a while back. Check out [`-(void) initToolbarItems`](https://github.com/pooriaazimi/BetterDictionary/blob/master/BetterDictionary/BetterDictionary.m#L90) method to see how I've done it (how the app gets there? `+(void)load --> -(id)init --> -(void)initToolbarItems`).

Comment: Hi Pooria! Thanks for the response, it gave me a hint where to move. Your approach doesn't seem to work well on Lion (Mail 5.2) - adding new toolbar buttons with the same identifier as original ones, after Mail restart, make appear several buttons with the same icon.. I guess a NSToolbar delegate has to be "swizzled", in order to make it work right.